# Нужно правильно обработать ошибку response

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, symfony, symfony3

Есть такой код

```
$.post(url, function (data) {
            if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                callback(data);
            }
        })
            .done(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .fail(function () {
                alert("error");
            });
```

Запрос уходит на контроллер url = бла бла.json
При успешном запрос все работает нормально
Нужно обработать 415 responce
В контроллере следующий код:

```
 return new Response(Response::HTTP_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE);
```

В `Route` `defaults = {"_format"="json"}, requirements = {"_format"="json"}`,

Получаю следующую ошибку в браузере:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in
>   415

В общем ошибку я поборол `return new` `Response('',Response::HTTP_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE);`

**А как обработать именно 415 ответ? чтобы в консоль не падала ошибка**

Comment: _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in 415_ где это происходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем так

```
 $.ajax(url,
            {
                method: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {

                },
                statusCode: {
                    415: function (xhr) {

                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так . 
`return new Response('неподдерживаемый тип данных', 415);`